# How to incorporate a g:link into an ordinary button?

Tags: html, grails, groovy, button, hyperlink

In my `grails` application there is a `view` with a a `g:link` tag - it works fine, but the visuals are kind of awkward. Therefore, I want to disguise that `g:link` with an ordinary button.

I've tried a `span class` and `input type="button"` but this did not do the trick.
 *Side note*: I don't want a `g:form` with an `submit` action.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amit Jain's answer worked but had some problems in ie 8 & 7 (looked like some kind of style overlapping error).  This solution worked in all browsers I tested

```
<button class="class" onClick="window.location = 'www.location.com' ">
    <g:message code="share.learnmore"></g:message>
</button>
```

Comment: There's no <g:link> which was requested

Comment: A <g:link> just results in an 'a' tag (<a href="/shop/book/list">Book List</a>).  Stuffing in a button is not good html.  There may be no <g:link> but my solution accomplishes what was really wanted

Answer (score 8):

g:link tag does nothing but at the end creates the anchor tag. So anything that you can put inside anchor tag, so with g:link.

You can simply write. 
<g:link class="create" action="create"><input type="button" /></g:link>

It appears to be a button to user but does the job of g:link tag.

Comment: A user posted a problem related to this solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003817/grails-glink-button-appears-larger-than-other-buttons/6005834#6005834

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use some javascript on the button and the javascript onClick method to perform the linking. A good alternative is to make a nice looking image instead.

If you want to avoid javascript then just use a form with method GET

Not really grails specific but you can probably do it quite easily with g:form somehow (I'm only just getting started with Grails myself)

EDIT: Re-reading your post, the most important thing to note is that I used input type="**submit**" which calls the action field in the form rather than just being a button.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the link and button will actually cause the button to fire twice !! Not recomended if you are doing some work off the back of it  ..