# Grails g:link button appears larger than other buttons

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a page that shows details of a bookInstance. On that page I want to put a button that uses a g:link to show some additional details.

I've got code that works mechanically, but the button doesn't appear correctly. The button's box doesn't shrink to the size of the content and there's a funny line added to the right hand side of the button.

Here's the code I'm currently using;

```
<g:form>
    <p><g:actionSubmit class="button" action="edit" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" />
    <g:actionSubmit class="button" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
    <g:link controller="ownedBook" action="list" params="['book.id': bookInstance?.id]" ><input class="button" value="${message(code: 'default.button.add.owner.label', default: 'Owned Copies')}" /></g:link>
    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${bookInstance?.id}" /></p>
</g:form>
```

[Image Link](http://i115.photobucket.com/albums/n304/Andrew-Riley/bigButton.jpg)

Comment: What's the output HTML?  Using any custom CSS?

Comment: Yes it's an html output.

Comment: The css for the button class is; 

.button {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #b2c951;
    border: 1px solid #245416;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #c9e06d;
}

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you build a live demo on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ . It won't take much time.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping an input button in your g:link.  Just use the message (that forms the button label) as the g:link contents.

Do you want and anchor tag, or a button?

Comment: I want a button looking link.

Comment: Or, use the g:link as I described above and modify its appearance.  In either case, embedding an input button inside the g:link is not what you want.