# Grails button syntax

Tags: grails, syntax, button, tags

Hey. Is there any special tag like this one:

```
<g:link controller="xx" action="yy_" id="${it.id}">
</g:link>
```

that don't need a form, but instead of a textLink is a button ?

Comment: [This looks very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356894/how-to-incorporate-a-glink-into-an-ordinary-button)

Comment: This isn't going to be news to anyone, but it's something that I have been focusing on the last couple of days: the browser provides right-click functionality to links for free (e.g., open in new tab). To disguise a link as a button is to hide navigation features from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `<button>` element, or an `<img>` or `<a>` element, then use the [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) tag to generate the URL that it requests when clicked

Answer (score 10):

You actually have it half done already. Just like in plain HTML, just put the button INSIDE the  tag. You can use the standard button CSS styling from grails.

```
view:

<g:link action="toLink"> 
   This is a grails app with a button link without a form or submit. Click this 
   <input type="button" value="I'm a Button Link" class="button"/> 
   and it should jump to the action.
</g:link>

controller:
def toLink = {
  render "It worked!"
}
```

Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<g:link controller="home" action="doLogout">
    <button type="button">Logout</button>
</g:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just put a `<div>` or `<img>` in the link tag that is styled to look the way you want...